# how to access value of a text box

Tags: javascript, html

I have following piece of code.

```
<td class='clsTblCell5' valign=top>
<select id='idMethodSel' class='clsTargetSel' style='width:220px; display:none ' Size=1    onchange='mtdAttachDlg("MtdAttach")'>
</select>
<table class='clsTblCellTI' style='border:1px solid #7f9db9;'>
<tr>
<td id='idMEthodSelTxt' style='width:210px; height:12px; padding-left:2px; padding-right:2px;border-style:none;'>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
```

I have keep the display of `select box` as none because I want to hide `select box` and place a `text box` instead of it, and can't remove it wholly as there is a very complex code ahead

I have got a script in which I made change as

```
var a =idMethodSel.[options].innerHTML;
idMethodSelTxt.innerHTML=a;
```

I have made several change but it is not working.

Please tell me the way by which I can make `idMethodSelTxt` value as that of `idMethodSel selcted` value.

Comment: Create a fiddle please..

Comment: In onchange='mtdAttachDlg("MtdAttach")' what is "MtdAttach" ???

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript, try the below code to get the selected value of `idMethodSel` and assign it to `idMethodSelTxt` textbox.

```
var a =document.getElementById("idMethodSel").value;
document.getElementById("idMethodSelTxt").value=a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by using jQuery it is very simple to do that
you just need to download jQuery library from [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)
include that 
and use the below code

```
 $('#idMethodSel').change(function(){
    var a = $(this).val();    
    $('#idMethodSelTxt').html(a);
    $('#idMethodSelTxt').html(a);
    $('#idMethodSel').hide();
   $('#idMethodSelTxt').show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the blelow code

```
function mtdAttachDlg(){

     var selBoxObj=document.getElementById("idMethodSel");
    //assign selected value to text box
     var selValue = selBoxObj.options[selBoxObj.selectedIndex].text;
     document.getElementById("idMethodSelTxt").value=selValue;

    //hide select box    
    selBoxObj.style.display="none";

    //show text box    
     document.getElementById("idMethodSelTxt").style.display="block";
}
</script>
```